# How to select a specific part

Tags: html, css

I have a div element with an id. I also have list items inside it. How would I just put a border around the div element itself, but nothing inside it. I have to put the list items inside as that is inside the div element itself. The example I have up is geo-village.com

HTML:

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/navbarstyle.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id=navbar>
            <ul>
                <li class=navbar_listitm><a href=/>Home</a></li>
                <li class=navbar_listitm><a href=/vatsim>VatSim Online Training</a></li>
                <li>
                    <div id=navbar_profile>
                        <?php
                            if ($_SESSION[loggedon] == true) {
                                echo "<a href=/profile>Good Day, $_SESSION[sessionun]</a>";
                            }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#navbar {
    background-color: #33ccff;
    padding: 5px;
    border-style: groove;
    border-color: darkblue;

}

#navbar li, #navbar a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline;
    color: blue;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold; 
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding: 7px;
}

.navbar_listitm {
    border-color: black;
    border-right-style: solid;
}

#navbar a:hover {
    color: cyan;
}

#navbar ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

#navbar_profile {
    float: right;
    border-color: black;
    border-left-style: solid;   
}
```

Comment: Can you please show us your html? It will help us find an answer for you faster...

Comment: edited jsut edited

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
#id {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

It should add that just to the div, not to anything inside.

For you to add it to the list items inside, you would have to do something like:

```
#id * {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Yep that what i have. It got applied inside.

Answer (score -1):

You're using `class=navbar_listitm` on your `<li>` elements. Then in your CSS, you have a border set to that class. If you remove that, the borders should disappear as well.

Your HTML:

```
<div id=navbar>
        <ul>
            <li class=navbar_listitm><a href=/>Home</a></li>
            <li class=navbar_listitm><a href=/vatsim>VatSim Online Training</a></li>
            <li>
```

Your CSS:

```
.navbar_listitm {
border-color: black;
border-right-style: solid;
```

}

So you *are* selecting the specific part, it's just that you've given it a class you probably didn't intend to give it.

Comment: yes i have a border for that class, actually just a black border line on the right side of the text. That is for seperation.